# Expectation of Integral of Brownian motion and time function with respect to time

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

How to calculate

$E[\int_0^T B_t f(t) dt]$

where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and $f(t) = e^{A(T-t)}$.

**Things I tried**

I feel like if swapping integral and expectation is allowed, then

$E[\int_0^T B_t f(t) dt] = \int_0^T E[B_t] f(t) dt = E[B_0] \int_0^T f(t)dt$

but I think there are some conditions so that we can swap the two.

**Background**

I am an engineering student and I know very little about stochastic integral. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Where is the reference for $d(B_t f(t) t) = f(t)B_t dt + f'(t)tB(t)dt + f(t)tdB_t$ ?   do you know about Ito differentiation?

Comment: Note that $E\left[B_t\right]=0$ for all $t\in [0, T].$

Comment: No need for Ito's formula Fubini's Theorem gives the answer as $0$.

Comment: @Khosrotash I am afraid not very well. I thought if you set $g(X_t, t) = B_t f(t)t$, $dX_t = dB_t$, then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = B_t (f'(t)t + f(t))$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial X} = f(t)t,\frac{\partial^2 {g}}{\partial X^2} = 0$... and ito's lemma says 
$dg = \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial g}{\partial X} dX$ is this wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @geetha290krm Hii, I searched a bit on Fubini, do you need the condition that $E[\int_0^T |B_t f(t)| dt]$ is bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain a description of the process. By Ito formula you have
$$
d\left(-\frac{1}{A}e^{A(T-t)}B_t\right)=f(t) B_t dt -\frac{1}{A}e^{A(T-t)}dB_t
$$
So
$$
\int_0^T f(s) B_s ds=-\frac{1}{A}B_T +\int_0^T\frac{1}{A}e^{A(T-t)}dB_s
$$
(as $e^{A(T-T)}=1$).The expectation is zero, as said in the comments